# How to change placeholder color to transparent with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, placeholder

I am trying to change the color of the placeholder but I cannot get the javascript right to call the element, could you please help me?

Im justing learning javascript and I tried to edit this with an WYSIWYG editor but since the content is dynamic, the whole functionality of autocompleted stopped working.

HTML

```
<input id="search" type="text" name="q" value="" class="input-text" maxlength="128" placeholder="Type here" autocomplete="off">
```

CSS

```
header .navbar .sc-bar #search_mini_form input.input-text
```

Comment: [How TO - Change Placeholder Color](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_placeholder.asp)

Comment: `::placeholder { opacity: 0 }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need javascript to do that unless you have some condition try to add classes to the input and then go with sass or plain css :

```
input#search::placeholder{
color:red;}
```

with sass :

```
input{
&#search{
    &::placeholder{
        color : red
    }
 }
}
```

in case you want to use javascript just add a class on a click event for exemple like that :

```
var d = document.getElementById("div1");
d.className += " otherclass";
```

an then :

```
input.otherclass::placeholder{
 color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think no need to use javascript, You can do that using css. Just add following code in your css file.

```
<style>
::placeholder {
  color: red;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
 color: red;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
 color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This seems to work, but it changed the text which is being typed in but I want to change the text which is displayed there by default.
it is an input field for search bar, where is written "type here" and I want to A/B test this with deleting this text and leaving the input field empty, so basically changing the color to transparent.

Comment: do you want to make placeholder transparent or the text that is being type?

Comment: the text, I alreadysolved it based on your suggestion so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
    <style type="text/css">
        ::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome */
          color: red!important;
        }
        :-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
          color: red!important;
        }
        ::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
          color: red!important;
          opacity: 1;
        }
        :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 4 - 18 */
          color: red!important;
          opacity: 1;
        }
```